# visual studio 2010 installation and setting problems

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I ve installed visual studio 2010. Installed successfully, on the main screen under the File tag the options are, team project , new file etc.
When I click on new file then a new screen appears in which templates are given.
I want vb.net but there is no vb.net template.
Whats wrong with it or how to add a vb.met template?
What shoud I do?

Answer (score 0):

Search under Visual Basics or in Other templates as below :

and click on Forms or type you want

[image]

Answer (score 0):

And if you are only interested in VB.net then make sure you have the settings right by clicking on Tools \ Import and Export Settings and import the Default Settings for Visual Basic Development.